# What is the point of having roles in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As per my understanding each database user is assigned a role. Each role owns a certain schema. The point of role then is to determine which schema a database user has access to.

Why not just remove the role and associate users directly with schemas?

Comment: You mean _Database Role_? _Application Role_? or both? Well the main purpose is _to easily manage the permissions in your databases_. For _Schema_ is a container of objects, such as tables, stored procedures, etc. Please [don't forget to visit and read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/overview-of-sql-server-security).

Comment: What happens to the schema if a user is removed?? Who still has access to that schema then??

Comment: As far as I know Schema must be transferred to another user before the user is deleted. SQL Server does not allow it. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles do not only manage the permissions at schema level. Roles are combinations of priviliege, that provide many other levels of control such as which user can access which database object (tables, procedures, ...), what type of queries it may execute (select, update, delete, insert), and so on.

Bottom line, roles give a flexible, fine-grained control over the way users access and use the database.

For more information see [the sql-server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/server-and-database-roles-in-sql-server).